# Dell Optiplex 7010 can't see 2nd sata hard drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bios, sata, dell-optiplex

I have this Dell Optiplex 7010 and am trying to add a 2nd SATA hard drive that is 10tb in size.  I can't seem to get it to recognize it consistently in the bios when its attached via SATA, even though I can see it via USB.

I have tried 2 drives, both 10TB.  One is toshiba and one is Western Digital.

Weird things happen.  The Toshiba I plugged into the computer unformatted.  The bios would not see it but if ran the diagnostic utility using <kbd>F12</kbd>, then rebooted, it will see it for one reboot only.

If I format either drive as ExtFAT GUID format using a USB adapter, as one big partition, the BIOS locks up completely. it will hang indefinitely.  I've let it sit there for like 5 minutes and it just shows the progress bar under the dell logo.  If I format as NTFS its just undetected as usual.  I have also tried 2 partitions of 5TB each but that probably shouldn't matter.  I haven't tried MBR.

I have tried powering completely down, removing all usb devices powering back, switching sata cables, switching sata connections to the board, etc.  I have updated to the latest Dell BIOS-- version a29 i believe.  I am in legacy boot mode, no secure boot, no UEFI.    Nothing seems to work.  I have an older 500gb sata drive and it sees that just fine.

Comment: Are you running the latest BIOS for it, and are you using UEFI ? (UEFI apparently does not work so good with large drives on that model - https://www.dell.com/community/Optiplex-Desktops/Optiplex-7010-MT-Maximum-Hard-Drive-Capacity/td-p/7514562 )

Comment: I updated the bios to the latest and i'm using legacy mode, not UEFI.

Comment: I would buy a cheap PCIe SATA controller card and attach the large drives to it. This should prevent the BIOS to recognize the drives at boot time and Windows can handle such large drives.

Comment: any advantage to PCIe over old fashioned PCI with a 7200 RPM HDD?  I think i have both slots available but would like the best speed.  @Robert

Comment: @fregas PCI is limited to ~133 MB/s which is about the speed one HDD can read data. Hence connecting two would reduce the maximum transmission speed. Also PCI is a very old system - not sure if PIC-SATA controllers support AHCI mode (also important for speed) and if you still find drivers for Windows 10.